# Subversion: how to undo svn rm + ci

Tags: svn

ok, so I was trying to check in a local copy and was frustrated when 'svn ci' wasn't working. I thought I could use 'svn rm' to remove the master version and then re-add the local copy. however this deleted the local copy. In a panic, I then used 'svn ci' again and it removed the file from version control. Is there anything I can do to get any of it back?

Comment: You committed a version which removed the file.  Roll back to the previous commit and the file will be back.  You can add it back manually or use the various `svn diff` etc commands to create a new commit which undoes the damage.

Comment: I should note here that `svn ci` is *NEVER* something you should do "in a panic". That's about the very *worst* thing you can do if you think something is messed up. As long as you don't commit your changes, you've only messed up your own local copy. As soon as you commit, your mistake goes to everybody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commited revision and now you want to get back to the older revision. Use reverse merge.

First, check which version you want to get back to:

```
svn log
```

And then just reverse merge (eg to revision 55):

```
svn merge -r HEAD:55 .
```

Merge will only change files in your working copy, so commit after that:

```
svn ci
```

Comment: Why do you specify `head:55` instead of `55:54` or `-c-55`?

Comment: @planner15 Have you included trailing dot?

Comment: @bahrep: why not? Your proposals are also valid.

Comment: I had not. Thanks! I don't suppose there is any way to get my uncommitted edits on my local copy back is there?